# Custom Product Icon

Tags: custom, image, icon

I'm trying to add a custom icon image for specific products.
I created an attribute  called b2g1

and im adding the following code to my list.phtml file

```
  <ul class="products-grid">
    <?php foreach ($_productCollection as $_product): ?>
        <?php
        $liClass = '';
        if ( $athleteHelper->isNew($_product) ) {
            $liClass = ' new-product';
        }
        if ( $athleteHelper->isOnSale($_product) ) {
            $liClass = ' sale-product';
        }
        ?>

        <li class="item <?php echo $liClass ?>">

            <?php if ($_product->getAttributeText('b2g1') == "Yes"): ?>
                <div class="b2g1">
                    <img src="<?php echo Mage::getBaseUrl(); ?>media/wysiwyg/b2g1-icon.png">
                </div >
            <?php endif; ?>


            <div class="item-wrap">
                <a href="<?php echo $_product->getProductUrl() ?>" title="<?php echo $this->stripTags($this->getImageLabel($_product, 'small_image'), null, true) ?>" class="product-image">
                    <?php echo $athleteHelper->getLabel($_product);  ?>
                    <?php echo $athleteImgHelper->getAdditionalImage($_product, $imgX, $imgY, true); ?>
                    <?php echo '<img class="regular_img" id="product-original-image-' . $_product->getId(). '" src="'. $this->helper('catalog/image')->init($_product, 'small_image')->resize($imgX, $imgY)
                        .'" data-srcX2="'. $this->helper('catalog/image')->init($_product, 'small_image')->resize($imgX*2, $imgY*2)
                        .'" width="'.$imgX.'" height="'.$imgY.'" alt="'.$this->stripTags($this->getImageLabel($_product, 'small_image'), null, true) .'" />'; ?>
                </a>
```

Not sure what I'm missing

P.S I'm fairly new to magento back-end developmet

Comment: What is the output of `var_dump($_product->getAttributeText('b2g1'));`?

Comment: @Christoph Farnleitner After var_dump I was getting the attribute return, however after testing different methods I was able to get it to work doing the following:


<?php $attributeValue = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')
     ->load($_product
     ->getId())
     ->getAttributeText('last_call');
    if ($attributeValue == 'Yes') {
     echo '<div class="last-call">
    <img src="/media/wysiwyg/last-call-icon.png" style="float:right;">
    </div >';
    }
    ?>



thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get it to work doing the following:

```
     <?php $attributeValue = Mage::getModel('catalog/product') 
       ->load($_product ->getId()) 
       ->getAttributeText('b2g1'); 
     if ($attributeValue == 'Yes') 
        { echo '<div class="b2g1"> 
                  <img src="/media/wysiwyg/last-call-icon.png" style="float:right;"> 
                </div >'; } 
      ?>
```